# Contextual closure type '(Any?) -> Void' expects 1 argument, but 2 were used in closure body

Tags: ios

I haved started ios recently and for the first time i am calling api for login and getting this error. Please help me out 
[image]

Comment: Copy/paste error, not photo. Even, prefers a Screenshot over a photo. And show the declaration of that method, it seems that the completionParameter you use doesn't respect the one needed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your completion closure returns only one parameter.

Meanwhile you're trying to use two: `result` and `error`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply . It helped me :) @ChooGoo